# Preferred formatting of screen/menu items?

Tags: discussion, markdown, formatting

Ok, so I was going to start editing a couple of questions and answers to clean up the formatting and make them a bit more readable, but thought I'd check in here first. Is there a preferred way to indicate a screen item?

For example, if I'd instruct someone on how to check the phone OS version, I'd use inline code (`Settings -> About phone -> Android version` or `Settings` -> `About phone` -> `Android version`) to separate the clickable items from body text.

Another option would be to use the kbd tag (<kbd>Settings</kbd>-><kbd>About phone</kbd>-><kbd>Android version</kbd>), but in my opinion this seems a bit bulky.

It would be nice to have a standard way to format these things. Suggestions, comments?

Answer (score 2):

I think as long as it's clear you're good to do whatever you want.  Like GAThrawn I would leave the keyboard buttons for actual buttons, though I tend to use bold or nothing for them myself.  I also tend to use inline code for menu items.

I suppose in an ideal world we would have a standard, or perhaps site-specific ways to indicate various Android UI elements, but I don't think it's particularly important.

Comment: Yes, I know it's not particularly important, but I like to have a unified formatting style. Maybe I'll stick with inline code.

Answer (score 1):

I normally save the <kbd>< kbd ></kbd> tags for actual hardware buttons (or at least buttons that are normally hardware even if they're sometimes soft) like <kbd>Power</kbd>, <kbd>Menu</kbd>, <kbd>Home</kbd>, <kbd>Back</kbd>, etc.

For menu options and clicking on items on the screen I'd normally either **bold** them (or for long options like descriptions on tick boxes "enclose them in quotes".

So for your example I'd say **Settings** -> **About phone** -> **Android version**

Or **Settings** -> **Display** -> tick "Auto-rotate screen"

Or giving a Xoom the "three-fingered salute" would be hold down <kbd>Power</kbd> + <kbd>Volume Up</kbd> at the same time.